# Painting Basement Foundation Walls - Prep Before Paint - Efflorescence

Tags: basement, repainting, cement, preparation

What are some methods to prep basement walls before painting that have Efflorescence?  This particular home had horrible gutters so water has been pooling against the foundation for years, if not decades. The basement walls have lots of Efflorescence and were seeping water in some areas where the water was pooling against the foundation.

Now that new gutters have been installed and water is properly routed away, the water has stopped seeping in and we are just left with dry Efflorescence on the walls.

What is the best method to clean the efflorescence, and then seal/prep the walls before we move on to a Drylok or elastomeric type paint?

Reading around I see people knocking it off with scrapers and grinders, and then using an etching type liquid before they rinse, dry, and paint the walls.

How should I go about prepping these walls now that the water issue is corrected, and I'm left with the efflorescence?

Comment: I don't see a problem with scraping or brushing (not sure I'd go as far as grinding), as long as you've taken care of the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Huesmann. Good point. I was thinking in my head wire brush but may grind some high spots. I have one spot where there was still a little water but the new gutter needs an extension. As long as that doesn't show wet on the next big rain, I'm going to town and getting it all painted up.

Comment: At most, I'd use a flapper wheel, not an actual grinder.  What's your method for "showing wet?"

Comment: @Huesmann Show wet meaning I can see the concrete actually wet on the floor. Before the gutters went up, on heavy rain the floor would actually get wet. Not pooled water, but it was enough to wet along the floor out a good foot. Most has been mitigated but 1 Corner still got a little wet even with the new gutters but I realized the water was still working its way back to the corner of the foundation so I put a small extension on the gutter and the water is now flowing downgrade and away. Supposed to be lots of rain in the next few days so I'll know if its all set.